# How do you go back to your main script after an import

Tags: python, import

I'm creating a script and have sucsessfully called on a second one, however, when the second one completes. The program just crashes - is it possible so after the import script section as completed, it will then continue back on the main script.

E.G.

My main one, which is titled Login_MainMenu.py as this script in:

```
if command == ('caesar'):
     import os
     os.system('caesarCipher.py')
     time.sleep(2)
     print("Your task is now completed")
     sys.exit()
```

I'm assuming I'd have to put something at the end of caesarCipher.py, which for now is:

```
mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
key = getKey()

print("\nYour translated text is:     ")
print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
```

Anyone got any ideas on how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Python doesn't crash without giving you a reason. Do you get an error? If so, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you have to do to return back. If it's crashing, you have a bug somewhere, but since you didn't tell us what the error message was, there's no way to help you.

However, you should not be running your other script via `os.system`. Import it and call its functions directly.

```
import caesarCipher
caesarCipher.get_translated_message()
```

assuming you've put the code into a function called `get_translated_message`, anyway.

Comment: Thank you! It's my first time doing an import on python and the problem was just simply the import os feature, my code just didn't seem to like it.